# How to access .Net dll in classic asp?

Tags: .net, asp-classic, .net-assembly

I know this is a repeated question ,but no solution worked for me . I am having a custom .Net dll . I have to use this in both aspx and asp pages.

Before accesing in asp ,i did the following things,

1.Build the dll project.

2.In VS2005 cmd prompt i ran sn -k MarkItUp.snk.

3.Referenced the key file in assembly.cs as [assembly: AssemblyKeyFileAttribute(@"C:\Projects\Xxx.xx.Utilities\bin\Debug\MarkItUp.snk")]

4.Then in VS2005 cmd prompt

```
 1.tlbexp Xxx.xx.Utilities.dll /out:Xxx.xx.Utilities.tlb

 2.regasm /tlb:Xxx.xx.Utilities.tlb Xxx.xx.Utilities.dll

 3.gacutil /i  Xxx.xx.Utilities.dll
```

everything was successful

5.Then i referenced the dll in the project

6.In my ASP page through VBScript i initiated the dll as

```
Dim strLogger
response.Write("Testing asp")
set strLogger=Server.CreateObject("Xxx.xx.Utilities")
```

Got the error as below

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
Server.CreateObject Failed
```

**I didn't do the regsvr,bse it was giving me "Entry point to  DLLRegisterServer not found" error**

Any inputs will be help me...

Thanks,

Comment: I fixed the issue by running the regasm in my DEV machine and creating the object with class name.

Like

 Server.createObject("Xxx.xx.Uitli.Classname")
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Make sure in the project properties that "Make assembly COM visible" is checked</s>

Trial and error seems to be the order of the day.   COM and ASP got a lot harder when Microsoft set access permissions to be strict by default.

Comment: yeah i already gave [assembly: ComVisible(true)] in my assembly.cs

Comment: Have you tried putting the assembly into COM+ manually?  and ensuring that the user IIS is running under has COM rights?

Comment: i managed to register the dll using regasm and its returning some string values from dll to my asp.. Now the problem is sending the error object as parameter from asp to dll function. Actually i am in process of implementiong log4net