# How to Add Custom DLL so IIS 8 VBScript application can use?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll, vbscript

I have inherited responsibility of setting up IIS after a server migration.  I have never used IIS before, however, I am the only one in my shop that has the programming ability to modify our intranet site(which is rare and wrote 10+ years ago by someone no longer here), which is hosted on the IIS.  I have limited exposure to .NET.

We were at IIS 6.0 and migrated to IIS 8.5.

The intranet site is  written in VBScript.  There is a .asp script that uses a DLL.  The DLL is 32 bit.

Here is a sample of the script and call:

```
<%response.write(DataTypeConversion.ConvertDate(x.value,"1","0"))%>
```

The DLL is named DataTypeConversion.dll   Within the DLL is a function ConvertDate().

Currently, when this piece of code executes, the script errors out and stops running.  I have tried to register the DLL with REGSVR32.

I have read where this may be an issue of IIS now being 64 bit trying to use a 32 bit DLL.  However, I have had no luck on that front either.

So, if I were to write a custom DLL, how can I make that DLL callable in a script like in the code example above?

Thanks

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, you could make a "Class Library" project.  Then, under "Project", "Properties", Application, "Assembly Information...", check the box to "Make assembly COM-Visible".  You might also want to read about "Strong Names".

This SO article has some pretty thorough instructions:  [How to access .Net dll in classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032541/how-to-access-net-dll-in-classic-asp)